# CSS3 - Dropdown Menu hover

Tags: css

I've created a dropdown menu and now I want to hover the main menu points but the list (the "dropdown") below that main menu not. I could give my `ul` and `li` a class to solve this but is there a smoother or cleaner way?

I appreciate every comment!

EDIT - CSS Code:

```
#mainnav li ul:not:hover {
    none !important;
}

#mainnav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #ff4040;
}
```

So the hover does work of course but its include all `ul` and `li`

Comment: Show us your html and the relevant css you have used. Best if you could create a working demo so we can see it in action. As a generic rule though the [`>` child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) comes handy in these cases.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'll look for the "child selector"

Comment: I also posted an answer after seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the  [`>` child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

```
#mainnav li ul{
    display:none;
}
#mainnav li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
#mainnav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #ff4040;
}
```

So you set the `ul` to be hidden by default (*the first rule*) and when you hover over `li` only its `ul` child (*and not deeper*) will show.